Prove that $\log_{10} (\phi)$ is irrational
Assume there exist intergers $a,b, b\neq0$ so that $\log_{10}\phi=\frac{a}{b}$. Then $\phi=10^\frac{a}{b}$ and $\phi^b=10^a$.
Now I need to find some contradiction. I know that there have to be $a,b>0$ since $\log_{10} \phi>0$. This means that $10^a$ is a whole number. What can I say about the power of an irrational number, $\phi^b$?

$\phi^b=m\phi+n$

If $x$ is irrational, we can say nothing about $ x^b$.

@hamam_Abdallah İf $x$ is algebraic yes. If $x$ is transandantal?

Note that $\phi^2=\phi+1$. So for every positive integer $n$ one can write $$\phi^n=a\phi+b,$$ for some suitable integers $a(\neq 0),b$. From your work it follows that if $\log_{10}(\phi)$ is rational, then there must be an integer $b$ such that $\phi^b$ is a power of 10, i.e., $m\phi+n$ must be power of 10 for some integers $m,n$. But this is impossible as $\phi$ is irrational.

And $a$ and $b$ are well-known positive integers.

@BobDobbs: True, although for purposes of this question knowing the existence of $a,b$ is sufficient.

$a$ must be non-zero. @LeeMosher

A very good point!

Theincredibleidiot gave a nice answer. Adding the following different argument relying on a little bit extra machinery. It should be  generalizable.
Let $\tilde{\phi}=(1-\sqrt5)/2=-1/\phi$ be the other root of $x^2=x+1$. If $\phi^b=10^a$ were an integer, it would follow that
$$\tilde{\phi}^b=(-1)^b\phi^{-b}=\frac{(-1)^b}{10^a}.$$
But we know that as both $\phi$ and $\tilde{\phi}$ are algebraic integers (as roots of a monic polynomial with integer coefficients), so are their powers. most notably
$\phi^{-b}=\pm(\tilde{\phi})^b$. Another basic fact about algebraic integers is that a rational number can be an algebraic integer only if it is an integer. For $(-1)^b/10^a$ to be an integer we need $a=0$, when also $b=0$, but that possibility is uninteresting for the purposes of this question.

Adding Galois theory to the mix would give the following. The only alois conjugate of $\phi$ is $\tilde{\phi}$, so the same applies to the powers
$\phi^b$ and $\tilde{\phi}^b$. Their sum is an algebraic integer stable under the non-trivial automorphism of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$, so the sum has to be an integer. But $\phi^b+\tilde{\phi}^b=10^a\pm10^{-a}\in\Bbb{Z}$ only when $a=0$ etc.

I've deleted this whole ridiculous exchange. The post is fine as-is.
